# Trying to print all my items in a list to rows and columns

Tags: python, list, format, multiple-columns, rows

So im trying to print the items from the list in to a 18x4 matrix or a table. I´ve tried doing it by using format but it hasn't seem to work.

[image]

This is the desired output I want to get from the list, but im not sure how to print the first 18 items in one column and then the next 18 items in second column and so forth. I hope the description is well enough explained since english is not my first language. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please post plain text in code blocks, not screen shots.

Answer (score 2):

Use nested loops for the rows and columns. In the inner loop, use a stride of `18` to get every 18th element starting from the index in the first column.

```
for i in range(18):
    for j in range(i, len(wireless_node_list), 18):
        print(wireless_node_list[j], end='\t')
    print()
```

Comment: Ive tried it but I seem to get the index twice in the table :/

Comment: I didn't realize the indexes were already in the file. So I don't need to print them.

Comment: Oh, you added the indexes in the loop that's reading from the file. I think it would make more sense to add them when printing.

Comment: Yeah I that makes more sense Ive got the desired results, thanks :). But I was wondering step by step what is happening in these two lines in the code: print(f"{j:2} {wireless_node_list[j]}\t", end='') print() . Im new to progamming so I found these two lines kinda confusing hehe. Is it also possible to o this with a simple format print statement?

Comment: The first one prints one field in a line, `end=""` means to end it with an empty string instead of a newline. Then after all the fields are printed in the row, `print()` prints a newline.

Comment: Yeah I kinda get it now. But Is possible to reduce the spacing between the columns to only 3 spaces instead of 5, which my code prints?. Because the test case for my submission for my assignment only allows the spaces between each column to be 3, sry for the many questions hehe.

Comment: I used a TAB to ensure that they all line up. You can change `end='\t'` to `end='   '` to make it 3 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to layout each row of output.  Figuring out how many rows to display requires some basic math if the goal is to have a target number of columns:

```python
# Some sample data
values = [x / 7 for x in range(50)]

cols = 4
# Figure out how many rows are needed
rows, extra = divmod(len(values), cols)
if extra > 0:
    # That means we need one final partial row
    rows += 1

# And show each row in turn
for row in range(rows):
    line = ""
    for col in range(cols):
        i = col * rows + row
        if i < len(values):
            line += f"{i:3d} {values[i]:3.9f}  "
    print(line)
```

Which outputs:

```
  0 0.000000000   13 1.857142857   26 3.714285714   39 5.571428571  
  1 0.142857143   14 2.000000000   27 3.857142857   40 5.714285714  
  2 0.285714286   15 2.142857143   28 4.000000000   41 5.857142857  
  3 0.428571429   16 2.285714286   29 4.142857143   42 6.000000000  
  4 0.571428571   17 2.428571429   30 4.285714286   43 6.142857143  
  5 0.714285714   18 2.571428571   31 4.428571429   44 6.285714286  
  6 0.857142857   19 2.714285714   32 4.571428571   45 6.428571429  
  7 1.000000000   20 2.857142857   33 4.714285714   46 6.571428571  
  8 1.142857143   21 3.000000000   34 4.857142857   47 6.714285714  
  9 1.285714286   22 3.142857143   35 5.000000000   48 6.857142857  
 10 1.428571429   23 3.285714286   36 5.142857143   49 7.000000000  
 11 1.571428571   24 3.428571429   37 5.285714286  
 12 1.714285714   25 3.571428571   38 5.428571429
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit brute force, but should work.  Just build your list and then do a little math with your indexes.

```
list = ["112312", "12321312", "9809809", "8374973498", "3827498734", "5426547", "08091280398", "ndfahdda", "ppoiudapp", "dafdsf", "huhidhsaf", "nadsjhfdk", "hdajfhk", "jkhjhkh", "hdjhkajhkj"]

build = {}
len = len(list)
rowCount = len//4 + 1
for i in range(rowCount):
    build[i] = []
    if i < len: build[i].append(list[i])
    if i + 4 < len: build[i].append(list[i + 4])
    if i + 8 < len: build[i].append(list[i + 8])
    if i + 12 < len: build[i].append(list[i + 12])

print(build)
```

This little sample tested out fine for me.